# How to call php class function in another function

Tags: php, oop

How can I call a class function in a global function with an object or included class file.

`cls.php` is the class file being used.

```
class tst { public function abc($i) { return $i*$i ; }
```

need to call abc function in xyzfunction in file `two.php`

```
include('cls.php');
$obj = new tst();
function xyz($j){$result = $obj->abc($j);return $result;}
echo xyz(5);
```

Calling `$obj->abc($j)` is not working. How can I call function `abc()`?

Comment: Pass the `$obj` variable as a parameter to function  `xyz(5,$obj)  .. function($j,$obj){ }`

Comment: Why is this tagged with Linux?

Comment: mind removing the banner effect?  in the opening line

Comment: there's an edit to remove it as I noticed now. *You* are the one who should have *not* used that banner effect and has been discussed on meta. Nor should we be the ones to accept [that edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/17250682).

Answer (score 2):

Try doing it this way, first `require_once` the file. Then create a new instance of the class by using the `$cls` code then execute a function by using the final line of code.

```
   require_once('cls.php');
   $cls = new cls();
   $cls->function();
```

Make sure this is inside your function e.g.

```
public function new_function() {
       require_once('cls.php');
       $cls = new cls();
       $result = $cls->function();
       return $result;
}
```

Then in your function send the response of that into your current function e.g.

```
$res = $cls->new_function();
$cls->function($res);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to instanciate the object inside your function, not outside.

```
 function xyz($j){
    $obj = new tst();
    $result = $obj->abc($j);return $result;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer the below code:

```
<?php

function xyz($j){   
    $obj = new tst();
    $result = $obj->abc($j);
    return $result;
}
?>
```

class instantiation has to be done inside the function call

Answer (score 0):

If your going to use it in more function you can instantiate the class outside the function and pass as a parameter to function like this .otherwise you instantiate the class inside the function .

```
<?php
class tst { 

    public function abc($i) { 

        return $i*$i ; 

    }
}

$obj = new tst();

function xyz($j,$obj){

   $result = $obj->abc($j);
   return $result;

}

echo xyz(5,$obj);  
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use **namespace**

```
namespace /tst 
class tstClass { publienter code herec function abc($i) { return $i*$i ; }
```

and then

```
use tst/tstClass
$tst = new tstClass();
$result = $obj->abc($j);
return $result;
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to inject in your dependency.

```
<?php

/**
 * @param int $j
 * @param tst $obj
 * @return int
 */
function xyz($j, tst $obj)
{
    $result = $obj->abc($j);
    return $result;
}
```

Don't instantiate the class inside the function, it's bad practice. Read up on dependency injection.